# How do I recursively list all NFS shares/datasets on OpenIndiana?

Tags: zfs, solaris, openindiana

Running OpenIndiana 2020. Issuing `zfs get sharenfs` lists all NFS shares for the most part. But how can I see if any subdirectories have been shared with different properties? Selecting a filesystem from the list, e.g. `tank1/testset` and using `zfs get sharenfs tank1/testset` only lists the parent status again.

```
admin@oi2:~$ zfs get sharenfs tank1/testset
NAME              PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
tank1/testset     sharenfs  on        local
```

I essentially want to return the information set in a command like the following example:

`zfs set share=name=pp,path=/pub,prot=nfs,sec=sys,rw=*,public rpool/public`

`cat /etc/dfs/sharetab` Does not list detailed info (particularly IP addresses) set in the "rw" field.

Issuing simply `share` lists

`testset@tank1/  /tank1/testset   rw   ""`

but no additional information. Does this mean there are no rw permissions set on this share?

Issuing `sharemgr show` results in:

```
default
smb
          /var/smb/cvol
zfs
    zfs/tank1
          /tank1
    zfs/tank1/testset
          /tank1/testset
```

For example I issued `share -o rw=@192.168.23.0,root=@192.168.23.0 /tank1/testset` but have no idea how to see this information after it has been set.

Comment: What happens with `zfs get sharenfs`

Comment: @ewwhite it lists all shares, their NFS status "Value" (on/off), and Souce (local/inherited from tank1, etc). But perhaps I am looking for file/directory ACLs rather than share info?

Answer (score 1):

I''m not sure on Solaris but on Linux you can view the NFS properties of a ZFS dataset with

```
cat /etc/exports.d/zfs.exports
```

or

```
 cat /etc/zfs/exports
```

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris 11.4, `zfs get export` does recursively list all NFS shares *without* showing every `sharenfs` properly for every filesystem and snapshot:

```
# zfs get share
NAME                   PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
export/backups         share     name=export_backups,path=/export/backups,prot=nfs,sec=default,root=@192.168  local
export/home            share     name=export_home,path=/export/home,prot=nfs,sec=default  local
export/home/ahenle     share     name=export_home_ahenle,path=/export/home/ahenle,prot=nfs,sec=default  local
export/home/...        share     name=export_home_...,path=/export/home/...,prot=nfs,sec=default  local
export/home/...        share     name=export_home_...,path=/export/home/...,prot=nfs,sec=default  local
export/home/...        share     name=export_home_...,path=/export/home/...,prot=nfs,sec=default  local
```